# Android AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6588)

Tags: android, listview

So, I don't understand why appear this error:

> 04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745): Process:
>   com.stm.classlife, PID: 10745 04-06 17:51:10.252:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10745): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   length=2; index=2 04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6588)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1632) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3763) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3632) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native
>   Method) 04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5868)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5920)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>   04-06 17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 04-06 17:51:10.252:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 04-06
>   17:51:10.252: E/AndroidRuntime(10745):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 04-06 17:51:10.252:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10745):  at java.lang.reflect.Meth

Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your crash logs here is the relevant line:

> android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6588)

```
if (mViewTypeCount == 1) {
    mCurrentScrap.add(scrap);
} else {
    mScrapViews[viewType].add(scrap);
}
```

Essentially this happens when you scroll a list view item off-screen and the recycler tries to reclaim it. View type for this view, as returned by `android.widget.Adapter#getItemViewType(int)`, is throwing your `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2`.

See [android.widget.Adapter#getItemViewType(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)):

> Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1.

I had the same problem. Check your override method for `getItemViewType(int)`, and ensure that you're returning consecutive zero-index numbers. Since your `getViewTypeCount()` method is returning 2, then your constants for item type must be 0 and 1.

Comment: I had the same issue. The 'getViewTypeCount(int)' method should always return the total number of view types in the adapter.  I was returning the count based on a logic which was making the app crash