# Breakpoint variable upon crash in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way in Android Studio, when we get crash, AS will point to the location of the crash?

I get this crash and it doesn't tell me where is the location of the crash, while I have checked all my variables and seems correct.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
    at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:8945)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:7243)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:6734)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:628)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `AbsListView.java`?

Comment: I think Indexing a value more than your length.I can find error if you post your code

Comment: @FiN it's a system component I suppose. OP look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471764/android-abslistviewrecyclebin-addscrapviewabslistview-java6588

Comment: Yes none of them is my class..
@fillobotto I will try it..

Comment: @fillobotto, I can't override those methods since I use BaseExpandableListAdapter not ListAdapter

Comment: Please post code. This is an inner component stack trace and it's pretty useless

Comment: Could you try with basic `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Android logcat will not always show Caused By statement  depending on the type of error however when it doesnt the first line in the error will most of the time be the cause of the Error. In your case `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3` this is clearly stated as an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` meaning you are accessing index [3] of an Array which has a length of 2.